# Why App cannot be loaded at the back of Pass

Tags: ios, google-maps, ios6, passkit

Before I can load this Google Map App at the back of Pass, but now why cann't it be loaded ? I use this Adam ID: 585027354. How to be able to load this App ? This is the back of my Pass: 
[image: back of Pass]

Answer (score 1):

It is the problem of App Store. Now I change to US App Store and there is no problem like before.